# Улучшения в инструментах модератора

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, дизайн, инструменты-модератора

Инструменты модератора, [статистика закрытий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days).

Есть таблица, в которой слишком длинные названия столбцов.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом деле там вот что:

```
<div class="col-4">Причина закрытия</div>
<div class="col-1">закрыт</div>
<div class="col-1">% от общего количества</div>
<div class="col-1">Отредактирован</div>
<div class="col-1">% закрытых</div>
<div class="col-1">открыто повторно</div>
<div class="col-1">% закрытых</div>
<div class="col-1">Отредактировано и открыто повторно</div>
<div class="col-1">% правок</div>
```

Похоже, они не вполне верно отражают смысл содержимого. Предлагаю переформулировать лаконично и верно.

Comment: А "Пользователь закрыт из-за вопросов не по теме" вас не смутило? :)

Comment: @Discord не заметил) надо тоже поправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="col-4">Причина закрытия</div>
<div class="col-1">закрыты</div>
<div class="col-1">% от общего числа</div>
<div class="col-1">правок</div>
<div class="col-1">% правок</div>
<div class="col-1">повторно открыты</div>
<div class="col-1">% повторно открытых </div>
<div class="col-1">повторно открыты после правки</div>
<div class="col-1">% открытых после правки</div>
```

Получается вот такая красота:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такие спряжения глаголов:

- Закрыт**ы** 5 вопросов
- Повторно открыт**ы** 3 вопроса
- Доля повторно открыт**ых** вопросов — 60%.

Comment: Возможно стоит только с заглавной написать заголовке всех колонок, что скажите?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо, конечно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: отправил варианты в транзифекс.

Comment: Спасибо! Обновил базу строк. Исправления должны быть доступны как только развернем новую сборку.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: проверил, уже доступны.